# Qualcomm HSUSB device driver issue

Tags: usb, usb-drivers

I have a Qualcomm HS-USB device on which I want to test my developed application. The problem I am facing is that the device drivers are not getting installed. I have tried the following steps:

1. Downloaded the Google USB drivers (latest).
2. Downloaded the ZTE USB drivers (the device is ZTE manufactered).
3. This device I have configured earlier also on a Windows 7 system and it worked fine. I dont know why it is not working this time on a new Windows 7 system.

Please help me to make the device driver work. Or please tell me if there is any other solution to this.

Comment: This site has mainly non-developers :P if you were to ask an actual development question, you should ask on StackOverflow (this one is fine here).

Answer (score 1):

As for all driver problems, you should first try the following:

1. Disconnect the device
2. Uninstall all drivers for it
3. Reboot
4. Install the official drivers (probably the ZTE-specific ones)
5. Reboot
6. Connect the device